# How to connect to my computer using my friends hotspot

Tags: networking

Hello I’m really new to Ubuntu and I’m really trying here because my family is really poor and we don’t have internet but my mom is actually the only one with unlimited data so every time she’s home I connect her hotspot to my phone and use my iPhone charger as a USB to try an connect her hotspot to my computer but it doesn’t work. But the funny thing is that it works only with my moms phone. I’m guessing because she has the internet. But I’ve tried adding all the specifications like iPv4 and iPv6 but i don’t understand why it doesn’t work. So i really need help getting this to work so I can have just some time to myself watching YouTube and and playing games but it doesn’t work. I really need help please answer as soon a possible. And if you can help in terminal that would be great too. Thanks bye *by the way my computer only uses an adapter so no WiFi*

Comment: Just to understand, you are trying to connect your computer to your mom’s iPhone to get Internet on your computer? Does your computer have WiFi?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have? (You can see that by opening System Settings app, clicking Details, and then clicking About).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your computer has working Wi-Fi, you shouldn't have to do anything in a terminal.

(If you do not have a Wi-Fi adapter in your computer, please add that information to your question, so someone can help you connect your computer to the iPhone's network using the lightning USB cable).

**On your iPhone...**

1. Tap the *Settings* icon
2. Tap *Personal Hotspot*
3. Turn on the *Personal Hotspot* switch by sliding it to the right
4. Tap *Wi-Fi Password*
5. Note the password, or enter a new password, if you want
6. Tap *Done*
7. Note the name of the phone's Wi-Fi network in the "CONNECT USING
   WI-FI" instructions section; it will say "1 Choose ..."

**On your Ubuntu computer...**

8. Click the top right corner of your screen
9. Click *Wi-Fi Not Connected*, to expand this section
10. Click *Select Network*
11. A dialog will appear on your screen, listing available Wi-Fi networks
12. Click on the phone's Wi-Fi network from step #7 above
13. Enter the password from step #5 above
14. Click the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button
15. Your computer will connect to the phone's Wi-Fi Hotspot